# Checking current value when overloading the assignment operator

Tags: c#

### Assumptions

Let's assume we have a class like so...

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator SomeClass(int value)
    {
        return new SomeClass() { Value = value };
    }
}
```

And then we're simply using an assignment, like so...

```
SomeClass mySpecialObj = 1; /* mySpecialObj.Value is now 1 */
```

### Scenario

Now, if I assign a value to an object that already has a reference, e.g.

```
SomeClass mySpecialObj = 1; // 1st assignment
mySpecialObj = 2; // 2nd assignment
```

### Question

On the 2nd assignment, is it possible to check the *current* value within the assignment operator?

```
public static implicit operator SomeClass(int value)
{
    // can I check mySpecialObj.Value here??
}
```

Comment: In what scenario would that be useful / make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not overloading the assignment operator, you're creating an implicit conversion from `int` to `SomeClass`. These are two very distinct things.

As such, `mySpecialObj = 2` effectively means:

1. Create a new instance of `SomeClass` using the integer `2`
2. And *then* assign that instance to the variable `mySpecialObj`

or,

```
mySpecialObj = new SomeClass{ Value = 2};
```

By now it should be clear that the answer is no, the conversion operation cannot know the value of the variable the new instance is going to be assigned to (*if* it is assigned to a variable).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in C#. The reason for this is that you are not overloading the assignment operator, you are defining an implicit conversion operator, which is not the same thing.

When you do this

```
mySpecialObj = 2;
```

C# creates a new, independent, object using the body of your conversion operator. By the time the reference is re-assigned, your code has already finished execution. Your code has no access to the variable being assigned, because that variable does not participate in the conversion defined by your operator. In fact, your operator can be used outside the context of an assignment - for example, if you do this

```
private static void Foo(SomeClass s) {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Value);
}
```

the presence of the implicit conversion operator lets you do this:

```
Foo(123);
```

Now `SomeClass` produced from `123` is not assigned to any variable at all.